# Erro durante tentativa de previsão usando XGBRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

Estava montando alguns modelos para previsão de dados em Machine Learning e acabei parando em um erro durante uma tentativa de previsão usando os algoritmos LinearRegressor e XGBRegressor. Abaixo segue o código:

```
pMeses = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]
pAnos = [2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020]
pQtdDias = [31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,31,29,31,30,31,30]
pMovS = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
pDiasUteis19 = []
pDiasUteis20 = []
pDiasUteis21 = []
pDiasUteis22 = []

for i in range(len(pMeses)):
    if(cal.get_working_days_delta(date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],1), date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],pQtdDias[i])) == 19):
        pDiasUteis19.append(1)
    else:
        pDiasUteis19.append(0)
for i in range(len(pMeses)):
    if(cal.get_working_days_delta(date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],1), date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],pQtdDias[i])) == 20):
        pDiasUteis20.append(1)
    else:
        pDiasUteis20.append(0)
for i in range(len(pMeses)):       
    if(cal.get_working_days_delta(date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],1), date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],pQtdDias[i])) == 21):
        pDiasUteis21.append(1)
    else:
        pDiasUteis21.append(0)
for i in range(len(pMeses)):   
    if(cal.get_working_days_delta(date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],1), date(pAnos[i],pMeses[i],pQtdDias[i])) == 22):
        pDiasUteis22.append(1)
    else:
        pDiasUteis22.append(0)

# print(pDiasUteis19)
# print(pDiasUteis20)
# print(pDiasUteis21)
# print(pDiasUteis22)

entrada2 = []
lr_predict2 = []
xgb_predict2 = []
for i in range(len(pMeses)):
    entrada2.append([[pMeses[i], pAnos[i], pQtdDias[i], pMovS[i], pDiasUteis19[i], pDiasUteis20[i], pDiasUteis21[i], pDiasUteis22[i]]])
    lr_predict2.append(int(lr_model2.predict(entrada2[i])[0]))
    xgb_predict2.append(int(xgb_model2.predict(entrada2[i])[0]))
    print('Mes: {:02d} LRegressor: {}'.format(pMeses[i], lr_predict2[i]))
    print('Mes: {:02d} XGBRegressor: {}'.format(pMeses[i], xgb_predict2[i]))
```

E esse foi o erro apresentado:

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['mes', 'ano', 'qtdDias', 'sMov', 'diasUteis19', 'diasUteis20', 'diasUteis21', 'diasUteis22'] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7']
    expected diasUteis22, diasUteis21, diasUteis19, ano, mes, diasUteis20, sMov, qtdDias in input data

training data did not have the following fields: f3, f2, f4, f7, f6, f0, f1, f5
```

Alguém que já manja de Machine Learning, poderiam me explicar porque o XGBRegressor *aparentemente* cruza as colunas do DataFrame para realizar a previsão?

Porque se eu já dei um procurada na documentação e não encontrei nada parecido. E se de fato for, acredito que não sirva para o meu modelo, pois se trata de uma **time series**.

Comment: Olá @ramonfsk, tudo bem? Você quer fazer um modelo de série temporal para forecast? Se sim, para uma abordagem com modelos ARIMA ou uma LSTM podem ser melhores. Senão, com o XGBoosting, entendo que seja necessário uma etapa de extração de features da série temporal para serem usadas em treinamento do modelo.

Comment: Fala Anderson, beleza? De fato, a utilização dos modelos ARIMA e LSTM são mais adequados para forecast. Quando eu fiz a pergunta não tinha me aprofundado no assunto, mas agora sei que não faz muito sentido eu utilizar esse algoritmo para previsões. De toda forma, agradeço pelo sua resposta.

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado, Ramon e bom trabalho também! Sucesso!